# Howto deal with the "There is not enough disk space to download messages" error?

Tags: linux, thunderbird, icedove

I've recently updaed to icedove 17.0.7 which is basically thunderbird 17.0.7. As you might have guessed i use Debian.

When i try to fetch new mails i get this message:
"There is not enough disk space to download messages..." (The message is in german though)

According to my df command:

```
    FILESYSTEM              TYPE     (=) USED      FREE (-) %USED AVAILABLE     TOTAL MOUNTED ON 
rootfs                  rootfs   [=========-----------]   44%     12,9G     22,9G /
udev                    devtmpfs [--------------------]    0%     10,0M     10,0M /dev
tmpfs                   tmpfs    [=-------------------]    0%    396,2M    397,0M /run
/dev/mapper/system-root ext4     [=========-----------]   44%     12,9G     22,9G /
tmpfs                   tmpfs    [=-------------------]    0%    992,0M    992,5M /dev/shm
tmpfs                   tmpfs    [--------------------]    0%    992,5M    992,5M /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                   tmpfs    [--------------------]    0%      5,0M      5,0M /run/lock
tmpfs                   tmpfs    [=-------------------]    0%    100,0M    100,0M /run/user
/dev/mapper/system-home ext4     [=========-----------]   43%     35,9G     62,8G /home
/dev/mapper/system-tmp  ext4     [==------------------]    7%      1,7G      1,8G /tmp
/dev/sda1               ext2     [==------------------]    9%    431,8M    477,0M /boot
/dev/sr0                udf      [====================]  100%        0B      7,1G /media/Fedora-18-Multi-Desktop
/dev/sdb1               vfat     [=-------------------]    4%      7,2G      7,5G /media/TIFFANYWEH
```

there is enough space left on my disk to store those mails. 
Does somebody know how to fix this?

Comment: just disabled my local disk quotas which i set up to save me from being unable to login when the disk gets full. these disk quotas do not allow me to use more than 95 % of the available diskspace. clearly this isn't the case here.

Comment: Where are the messages stored?

Comment: on my /home at my local disk

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the version 17.0.7. I installed thunderbird version 17.0.8 from the homepage putting it to /usr/local/share/alternatives/thunderbird and linked it to /usr/local/bin/icedove also i linked the ~/.icedove to ~/.thunderbird. when i start thunderbird now with quotas enabled everything is working fine.

Comment: filed a bug report to the debian maintainers.

Comment: Well done for sorting it out. Could you write up a quick answer detailing what you did?

Answer (score 1):

**The Problem:**

As i analysed the problem it occurs only with disk quotas enabled on the partition where your local profile is stored. Disabling quotas with

```
quotaoff -vau
```

does fix the problem with tunderbird/icedove. However the problem remains because in the environment i am working with the use of quotas is crucial.

**The Solution:**

My investigation on how to fix this problem came to the conclusion that there already is a fix for that so I downloaded the [latest version](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/all.html) of Thunderbird which is 17.0.8.

Untar the package like this:

```
tar xvfj thunderbird-17.0.8
```

and move the unpacked folder to a proper location like:

```
mv thunderbird /usr/local/thunderbird-17.0.8
```

Change into directory and link thunderbird to icedove.

```
ln -s /usr/local/thunderbird-17.0.8/thunderbird-bin /usr/local/bin/icedove
```

Set permissions on the folder:

```
chown -R root:root /usr/local/thunderbird-17.0.8/ && chmod -R 755 /usr/local/thunderbird-17.0.8
```

The final steps requires to link you profile to the the folder thunderbird will create.

```
ln -sf ~/.icedove ~/.thunderbird
```

Now start thunderbird by typing icedove in the konsole and it starts thunderbird with quotas enabled.